# Django Admin Interface: Extend the 'groups' page show its users and allow adding new users

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

In the default admin interface, the group page is not very comprehensive. (attached a picture) I can't see the users that are part of that group, and I can't add any users from there (I have to go to the user's profile, and add them to the group one by one)

I tried to extend this functionality this from `admin.py`, but not sure how to do it. If `auth_group`, `auth_user` and `auth_user_groups` were user defined models in `models.py`, I'd probably do something like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from myproject.models import Group, User, GroupUserMembership 

class MembershipInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = GroupUserMembership
    extra = 1

class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (MembershipInline,)

class GroupAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (MembershipInline,)

admin.site.register(Group, GroupAdmin)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

But this would result in

`Exception Value: The model Group is already registered`

(also I don't know how can I import `auth_user_groups`)

**TL;DR** How do I extend the Django Admin Interface to display the many-to-many relationship between the default auth models `User` and `Groups`? (like `Permissions` in the picture below)

[image: Django default Admin Interface for groups]

Answer (score 1):

You must first unregister the default User(model name) model admin before registering your own.

Try this

```
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```